# Flutter theme data why this color does not work but the others do

Tags: flutter

I just started to learn flutter, so I was curious about why this color doesn't work but others one do it.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hey',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurpleAccent),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Heyyy'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Testing'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

`Colors.deepPurpleAccent` doesn't seem to work but `Colors.deepOrange` it does. Why? Thanks!

### Update:

---

I just tried as @yahya parvar said. For some reason if I do that it gives this error message.

`The constructor returns type 'Color' that isn't of expected type 'MaterialColor'.`

So I tried using the color from a const variable, and it doesn't give me any error but the screen is full of white.

[image]

However, I was just more curious of why this is happening and why colors like `Colors.deepPurpleAccent` doesn't seem to work while others like `Colors.deepOrange` does it than the color itself to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is you want to use a color with type of `MaterialAccentColor`
but `ThemeData` class takes `MaterialColor`type , which has different

if you want to set a background for your entire screen there is several way to do that one of the is the one that you want to use another one is set a background for scaffold try this

```
Scaffold(background:Colors.deepPurpleAccent)
```

Comment: I just updated the post because it was eassier for me to explain all that!

Comment: i updated my answer try that and tell me the result